# Minimum sum route through numpy array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math

This is a two part question.

**Part 1**

Given the following Numpy array:

```
foo = array([[22.5, 20. ,  0. , 20. ],
             [24. , 40. ,  0. ,  8. ],
             [ 0. ,  0. , 50. ,  9.9],
             [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  9. ],
             [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2.5]])
```

what is the most efficient way to (i) find the two minimal possible sums of values across columns (**taking into account cell values greater than zero only**) where for every column only one row is used and (ii) keep track of the array index locations visited on that route?

For example, in the example above this would be: `minimum_bar = 22.5 + 20 + 50 + 2.5 = 95` at indices `[0,0], [0,1], [2,2], [4,3]` and `next_best_bar = 22.5 + 20 + 50 + 8 = 100.5` at indices `[0,0], [0,1], [2,2], [1,3]`.

**Part 2**

Similar to **Part 1** but now with the constraint that the row-wise of sums of `foo` **(if that row is used in the solution)** must be greater than the values in an array (for example `np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10])`. In other words `sum(row[0])>array[0]=62.5>10=True` but `sum(row[4])>array[4]=2.5>10=False`.

In which case the result is: `minimum_bar = 22.5 + 20 + 50 + 9.9 = 102.4` at indices `[0,0], [0,1], [2,2], [2,3]` and `next_best_bar = 22.5 + 20 + 50 + 20 = 112.5` at indices `[0,0], [0,1], [2,2], [0,3]`.

My initial approach was to find all possible routes (combinations of indices using `itertools`) but this solution does not scale well for large matrix sizes (e.g., `mxn=500x500`).

Comment: Part 1 is straightforward, you need to explain clearly what is Part 2, especially what is row-wise sum must be greater than the values in the array, if all the values are positive the sum is always greater than any one of the values.

Comment: With row-wise sum I mean `62.5` for `row 0`, `72` for `row 1`, `59.9` for `row 2`, `9` for `row 3` and `2.5` for `row 4`. Then with must be greater than the values in the array I mean `sum(row[0])>array[0]`, `sum(row[1])>array[1]` etc.

Comment: In my example I used an array of all 10's which may be confusing. If the array is instead `np.array([10, 20, 5, 3, 25])` then the constraint is that `sum(row[0])>array[0] = 62.5>10=True`, `sum(row[1])>array[1] = 72>20 = True`, etc.

Comment: In both cases, your constraint fails to hold for row indices strictly greater than 1. Did you intend to add the condition that at least one element must be selected in the given row for the constraint to be included, or something like that? Even then, in your `minimum_bar` in Part 2, why is the given solution considered feasible, when the only element from the row with index 1 is 8, which is less than 10?

Comment: @fuglede thanks for your questions. Not sure what you mean with the first of your questions. In terms of the second question, you're right - have amended the question.

Comment: Regarding the first question: In your example, the sum of the selected elements in the final row is 0 (as no elements are selected), and 0 is less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that I came up with (hopefully I didn't misunderstand anything in your question)

```
def minimum_routes(foo):
    assert len(foo) >= 2
    assert np.all(np.any(foo > 0, axis=0))

    foo = foo.astype(float)
    foo[foo <= 0] = np.inf
    foo.sort(0)

    minimum_bar = foo[0]

    next_best_bar = minimum_bar.copy()
    c = np.argmin(np.abs(foo[0] - foo[1]))
    next_best_bar[c] = foo[1, c]

    return minimum_bar, next_best_bar
```

Let's test it:

```
foo = np.array([[22.5, 20. ,  0. , 20. ],
                [24. , 40. ,  0. ,  8. ],
                [ 0. ,  0. , 50. ,  9.9],
                [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  9. ],
                [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2.5]])

# PART 1
minimum_bar, next_best_bar = minimum_routes(foo)
# (array([22.5, 20. , 50. ,  2.5]), array([24. , 20. , 50. ,  2.5]))


# PART 2
constraint = np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
minimum_bar, next_best_bar = minimum_routes(foo[foo.sum(1) > constraint])
# (array([22.5, 20. , 50. ,  8. ]), array([24., 20., 50.,  8.]))
```

To find the indices:

```
np.where(foo == minimum_bar)
np.where(foo == next_best_bar)
```

Comment: I like the approach although this does not fully seem to solve the problem at hand. Two things in particular: (1) Your part 2 does not solve the problem. Given you use the second row only in the final column (i.e., `value=8`) this is an invalid solution if the constraint is `sum(row[1])=8>10=False`. (2) Your approach to finding index locations won't work (I believe) if there are multiple indices with the same values (say there are multiple places where `22.5` occurs for example).

Comment: I believe the original question was poorly phrased. What I meant for Part 2 was that the row-wise sum is computed only on indices used on that route. For example: in the minimum route `22.5, 20.0, 50.0, 8.0` the rows that are used are `row 0 (for 22.5, 20)`, `row 1 (for 8.0)` and `row 2 (for 50.0)`. In which case both rows 0 and 2 are fine since `22.5+20>10` and `50>10` but row 1 isnt' since `8<10`. Hence the solution is wrong.